# Sending single observation from a dataset to a users email within the observation SAS

Tags: loops, email, sas, filenames

I'm fairly new to SAS coding and I am wondering about this problem.
I have a table that contains a number of variables and one variable that is the users email.

I want to send the single observation to the email within that observation.

Looking around I thought something like this might work?

```
data work.dataset;
    set work.dataset;
        do %let mail = useremail (variable with users email);
        filename mailbox email &mail;
        subject = "subject";
        data _null_;
        file mailbox;
        put;

run;
```

I am very aware that I could be way off with that though.

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Sounds like you want to send a separate email for each observation in the dataset? Or perhaps one observation for each distinct value of the USEREMAIL variable with data from all of the observations for that user?  Is that right?   Look at the email directives. https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=n0ig2krarrz6vtn1aw9zzvtez4qo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p19fmiur9hdhswn0z9ghrki675a2

Comment: Hi Tom,
Yes, If possible I'd like to send one observation for each distinct value of the USEREMAIL variable with data from all of the observations for that user.
I'll take a look.
Thank you!